# Integration of pentaho with cassandra

Tags: pentaho

Could you please share the steps to integrate penatho with cassandra.
I have tried using'data-integration' plugin.But when i was trying to preview the data i am getting the below error 'Sorry,during preview there weren't any rows to display for this step'. and 'unable to save the repository element'.

thanks in advance

Comment: Would you mind including the code that is causing you these errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Cassandra Input** step in Pentaho DI for connecting and reading the data from Cassandra. Similarly you can also use **Cassandra Ouptut** step. You can read more about these in the pentaho wiki:

- http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Cassandra+Input
- http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/How+To+Read+Data+From+Cassandra

The possible reason for those two errors are connection issues. I assume the step is not able to properly connect to the cassandra server. check your cassandra db configurations.

Hope it helps :)